# How to order query results based on date field in parent model in rails4/activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have models

```
class Run < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :race
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :runs
end
```

Race has a date field and run has a name field.

I would like a query to present all runs from specific name ordered by date field in the race.

I have tried following, but it doesn't sort correctly, results are presented randomly.

```
Run.where(:name => 'foo').joins(:race).order('races.date ASC')
```

Thinking that problem might be in the date field I also tried sorting based on id in Race, but results were incorrect as well. I also tried placing join as first element after Run, but no change in results.

SQL generated is as follows:

```
"SELECT `runs`.* FROM `runs` INNER JOIN `races` ON `races`.`id` = `runs`.`race_id` WHERE (name = 'foo')  ORDER BY odds ASC, races.date ASC"
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some `default_scope` in either model?

Comment: Also, what is the generated sql statement?

Comment: @thepanu add .to_sql after `order(...)` and paste it here please. IMHO you are doing everything fine.it should work

Comment: Added sql output. Yes, there is default scope in run which orders by another field in run.

Comment: `default_scope` looks cool at first, but no kidding it causes lots of troubles especially shared Models. I ran into many problems including ambiguous columns selections and slow query which took me lots of time to figure out those unexpected behaviors. Here is some [explanation](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using default_scope for your model, Active Record always uses your **order** method by 'odds' first. Do not use **default_scope** unless you really have to. You'll probably be better off with [regular scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)(look at section 14).

You can use [unscoped](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class) also, which makes AR "forget" the default_scopes. Use it like:

```
Run.unscoped.where(:name => 'foo').joins(:race).order('races.date ASC')
```

There is also the **reorder** method that also overrides the default scope order method:

```
Run.where(:name => 'foo').joins(:race).reorder('races.date ASC')
```

Comment: There it was in plain sight. Thanks.